# How to debug a Release build of my WebAPI application?

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017

I use VS 2017 for building my WebAPI. In the Staging environment i have my visual studio installed as well.

I have a folder C:\WebApi where the published files live

1. From TFS i take the latest in the C:\Source folder.
2. Rebuild the solution in VS 2017
3. Publish the Project to C:\WebApi

Now when i check the C:\WebApi, i see the pdb file also

Now i need to do debug, the application.

I attached the debugger to the w3wp process, but it does not hit

Let me know how can i debug my application

Comment: In Release build there are some optimistaions applied to your code, so debuging will not work well (for example, some breakpoints may not be hitting, since this line of code does not exist/modified). Solution - don't debug release build.

Comment: @Thomson Check the service URL in client. Make sure that service is hosted on your machine if you are attaching the w3wp process of local machine.
Is your problem related to debugging the service in dev environment or debug service hosted in prod environment?

Comment: what command did you use to rebuild the solutions. is it dotnet core?  **Need more details please!** PDB files are just symbols that means nothing without source files.  If you build using Release you can't just attach. You also cannot attach over internet, if that is what you are trying. You need a VPN - Are you sure you published to the WebAPI directory that IIS is looking at? And lastly... you shouldn't be debugging on your release servers.. *sigh* You should be able to reproduce problems on your dev, ship it and work the same. If not.. you have a release cycle problem. Use CI/CD

Comment: @vasily.sib thats why build emits symbols (PortablePDB - Latest msbuild, aka dotnet core), which tell your IDE how the DLL is arranged and how to hook into source. Now in the latest msbuild  so that you can attach to Release builds using SourceLink using Visual Studio 2017 15.8+. I have done it on Release DLL's and it works well! Actually its f***ng amazing!  - Just Thomson is doing dev work on the release servers? That is the wrong way around.. making life difficult for him. You should be able to debug everything on local and deploy as is to release.

Comment: @ppumkin thats why i'm telling _"will not work well (for example, some breakpoints may not be hitting)"_. For example, some methods maybe simplified and replaced by others, so breakpoints on this methods will never be hitted, eventhough that code of this methods may be invoked.

Comment: No.. all breakpoints will be hit :D

Comment: @vasily.sib, i have an issue on the staging environment. Iam not able to replicate this in dev. I have logging mechanisms pointing to which method its creating a problem. But as its a staging environment, i have the luxury to debug, which i want to try . I use VS 15.5.1

Comment: @ppumkin check [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ws3ZLf). Copy-paste this in VS (console app) and try to hit any breakpoint in `DoA()`, `DoB()` or `DoC()` in **Release** build. You can't hit breakpoint if there is no code under this breakpoint, it for sure.

Comment: @Thomson do you have issue with staging **environment**, or release **build**? deploy **debug** build to staging and debug it in normal way?